# How can i get more then one input in 2d array, to save and out put user info

Tags: c#, arrays, 2d

```
static void Main2(string[] args)
{
    string[,] items = new string[2, 2];

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Item Name:");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Item Price:");
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Item Quantity:");

            items[i, j] = Convert.ToString(Console.ReadLine());
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Item Name: " + items[i, j]);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Item Price: " + items[i, j]);
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Item Quantity: " + items[i, j]);
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

How can I get more than one input in a 2d array, to save and output user info?

Comment: You prompt for Name, Price and Quantity then only collect one thing from the user.  Note that a more sensible way to manage a number of related bits of data is using a Class, then a collection to store many of them.

Comment: tried console.ReadLine(); and Console.WriteLine();

Comment: a separate class?

Comment: put the user prompt in another class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use the array to hold the user's answers, then maybe this helps:

```
string[,] items = new string[2, 3];
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Item Name:");
    items[i, 0] = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Item Price:");
    items[i, 1] = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Enter Item Quantity:");
    items[i, 2] = Console.ReadLine();
}

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Item Name: "+items[i,0]);
  Console.WriteLine("Item Price: " + items[i, 1]);
  Console.WriteLine("Item Quantity: " + items[i, 2]);
}
Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the most readable way to do this would be to create a simple class to store the data, and then store a collection of these classes in a `List`. You can `override` the `ToString` method on the class, and you can create a simple wrapper for getting strongly typed data from the user (for `Price` and `Quantity`, we want them to only enter numbers):

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return $"Name: {Name}, Price: {Price:C}, Quantity: {Quantity}";
    }
}
```

Now a few wrappers to prompt the user for input and get strongly-typed results:

```
private static int GetIntFromUser(string prompt)
{
    int result;

    do
    {
        Console.Write(prompt);
    } while (!int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result));

    return result;
}

private static decimal GetDecimalFromUser(string prompt)
{
    decimal result;

    do
    {
        Console.Write(prompt);
    } while (!decimal.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out result));

    return result;
}

private static string GetInputFromUser(string prompt)
{
    Console.Write(prompt);
    return Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Then we can two items from the user in a loop:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var items = new List<Item>();

    for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++)
    {
        var itemNumber = $"Item #{i + 1}";
        var item = new Item
        {
            Name = GetInputFromUser($"Enter {itemNumber} Name: "),
            Price = GetDecimalFromUser($"Enter {itemNumber} price: "),
            Quantity = GetIntFromUser($"Enter {itemNumber} Quantity: ")
        };

        items.Add(item);
    }

    foreach (var item in items)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```